# How should I export CSV from excel and keep numeric values with their original number of decimals?

Tags: excel, csv, decimal

Every time when I export(save as CSV) data from Excel(xlsx) to CSV format, those numeric values will only have 2 decimals in CSV file.

Is there any solution that I can keep their original values (for example, some values may have 4 decimals and I want to keep all)?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How do you know for sure that there are only 2 decimals in your CSV file? I just created an Excel sheet with just one value `0.1234`, I exported to a CSV file and while opening this in a text editor (Notepad++), I indeed saw `0.1234`.

Comment: I checked mine. There are only 2 decimals...

Comment: @Alex - *Where* are there only 2 decimals? in Excel? in the csv? in both? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52648606/edit) to provide screen shots of both? What number format are the cells in Excel?

Comment: A [`.CSV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is unformatted, comma-separated data, stored in plain text.  If you're saving an Excel worksheet as a `.CSV` with **File > Save As**, then you are getting **exactly** the number precision that your data is actually stored with, and **none** of the formatting (like number display formats or font properties).

Comment: The saved CSV file will have only 2 decimals...That's weird. It could be a format issue in excel I guess...

Comment: How are you examining the CSV file?